# Beginner python3 question about elif statement syntax and the use of print_function

Tags: python

Trying to build a simple script for returning disk, cpu usage and network connectivity checks. I keep getting errors in my elif statement syntax. I've tried revising this for 3 days and finally am not getting errors in the str format line 36 but now i get an invalid syntax error on line 37 (line containing only "else:". I read that in earlier python versions you had to import print_function, which is why it is listed, though I believe you shouldn't need to do this in Python3. Any suggestions or insight into why this error is occurring would be very much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import shutil
import psutil
import print_function
from network import *

def dsk_free(disk):
    df = shutil.disk_usage(disk)
    fre = df.free / df.total * 100
    dsk_out = 'Disk usage = {}%'.format(fre)
    return (dsk_out)

def cpu_ok():
    cpuse = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    cpu_out = 'Cpu usage = {}%'.format(cpuse)
    return (cpu_out)

def check_disk_usage(disk):
    du = shutil.disk_usage(disk)
    free = du.free / du.total * 100
    return free > 20

def check_cpu_usage():
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    return usage < 75

x = dsk_free
y = cpu_ok

if not check_disk_usage("/") or not check_cpu_usage():
    print("ERROR! Shut down immediately!")
elif check_connectivity() and check_localhost():
    print("Everything is awesome! Disk Usage is {}% and Cpu usage is {}%".format(dsk_free(),cpu_ok())
else:
    print("Network connection failure!")
```

---

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Check the number of `(` and `)` in the line before the `else`. And get rid of this `import print_function`.

Comment: please provide the whole error message

Comment: File ... line 37
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Matthias, you were right. Missing the ellipse and the import was not necessary, thanks. Still working on it calling my functions right but getting closer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
if not check_disk_usage("/") or not check_cpu_usage():
    print("ERROR! Shut down immediately!")
elif check_connectivity() and check_localhost():
    print("Everything is awesome! Disk Usage is {}% and Cpu usage is {}%".format(dsk_free(),cpu_ok())
else:
    print("Network connection failure!")
```

in your second elif statement, where you have your print statement,  you are missing the finishing ), add one more ) at the end and you should be good to go

Comment: Also, there is no definition of the function `check_connectivity()`.

Comment: Thank you all, should have caught the missing ellipse.. error code was   File ... line 37
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Rusty, the function is imported from network at the top.

Comment: Aha, thank you, I don't have `network`.